# HD not visible in Finder

Tags: macos, osx-lion, macbook-air

I have bought a Macbook Air (with Lion) but I am not able to find the Devices section in Finder. I want to see my HD in Finder. I just explored  Disk Utility and found that there 120GB hdd named HD Macintosh. How can I see that in Finder?

Comment: Don't you see it in a Finder window when you press `⌘⇧C` (or *Go → Computer*)? Also, what is the output of `ls -l@ /Volumes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just need to enable viewing of external drives in the Sidebar. You can do this by:

1. Open a new Finder window.
2. Go to the menu Finder → Preferences or type <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> .
3. Go to the Sidebar section.
4. Make sure that **External disks** is fully checked:

[image]